# Vote to close doesn't do anything. Chrome. Mac OS X

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Steps to reproduce:

Close -> Why should this… click "exact duplicate" -> Paste the URL of the "duplicated". If you click VOTE TO CLOSE right there, nothing happens.

You have to press "enter" on the URL text box so the form will "load" the question.

I don't know if this is by design. But I spent a couple of minutes clicking Vote to Close and nothing happened (even after reloading the page).

When I decided to press "enter" it worked.

Chrome 8. OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

Martín, I'm using Chrome 9.0.597.84 and I'm not able to reproduce this. The duplicate question content loads right away. Or when I pasted an incorrect URL it displays the "Unable to find a question id in your input - please enter a question url or numeric id" message.

How are you pasting the url? Using mouse click or <kbd>cmd+v</kbd> ? If this is an issue with Chrome 10.6.6 only, then we don't support Beta browsers.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 8.0.552.237 and Mac OS X 10.6.6 ;)

Comment: …and pasting with cmd+v

Comment: Sorry I misread. I was on Chrome 8 too when I first read your question. Then I realized I wasn't on the latest official build of Chrome so I upgraded to 9. And I wasn't able to repro. I wonder if it's related to this bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60057 (I believe it's been fixed in the latest build)

Comment: Well I didn't even know there was a new Chrome :) I will upgrade to 9 anyway, but I have no idea if there's a workaround in 8.

Comment: @Jin @Martín n00bs. I'm on Chrome 10. :)

Comment: @kyle can you repro this on Chrome10?

Comment: @Jin works fine on Chrome 10

Comment: @Jin: this happens to me on chrome 8 as well.  I can get it to load the dup by hitting tab.

Comment: @Kyle I'm not that "edge" ;)